# Reshape or Pivot columns into index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe with index titled **my_index**

```
my_index | Lunch | Dinner | 
---------|-------|--------|
Yes      |  100  | 300    | 
No       |  20   | 400    |
```

I am trying to **reshape or pivot** the dataframe so that the my_index becomes the column names and the row values appear as this:

The desired outcome will be:

```
 my_index | Yes | No
    ------|-----|---
    Lunch | 100 | 20
    Dinner| 300 | 400
```

I have tried using pivot_table and pivot but am stumped!

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `df = df.T`

Comment: That would be it! haha i forgot about Transposing the dataframe! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.T
```

Transposes the dataframe!